# Где правильно поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Этот вопрос совершенно не реальный то есть я не встречал людей которые вот так любопытны.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос совершенно нереальный, то есть я не встречал людей, которые **вот так** (= в такой степени) **любопытны.**

Пример:

Я знаю только нескольких людей, **которые вот так** относятся к жизни. [Леонид Якубович, «Общая газета», 1998]

Сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью. Запятые ставятся перед союзом ТО ЕСТЬ и союзным словом КОТОРЫЕ. Сочетание "вот так" запятыми не выделяется.

**НЕ пишется слитно** при усилении утвердительного смысла прилагательного (совершенно нереальный).